Apply attribute directive to the ngForTemplate of each item
I am building a standalone component that receives a collection of objects to render with ngFor. The templateRef, use to render those objects is taken by means of a ContentChild.
      <ng-template
        ngFor
        let-item
        [ngForOf]="items"
        [ngForTemplate]="template"
        [ngForTrackBy]="trackByFunction"
      >
      </ng-template>

Here is the usage:
<my-component [items]="items">
  <ng-template let-item>
    {{item.name}}
  </ng-template>
</my-component>

I would like to add a directive to each item that would do some simple attribute stuff, like add a class, hold a dimension. The idea is that this component will be used instead ngFor to do more advanced logic. I want to avoid adding the directive to the html on the usage side. I also want to be able to reach this directive from MyComponent.
How can I do this?
Edit:
Even if I'd place the directive on the usage side, I still need a way to query for that rendered items somehow. So far I found no combination of ContentChild/ViewChild and read that would help here.

The typical is pass the template as input in a component, e.g.
@Component({
  selector: 'list-items',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
  @if(template)
  {
    @for (item of items;track $index)
    {
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template;context:{$implicit:item}">
      </ng-container>
    }
  }
  `,
})
export class ListItems {
  @Input() items: any[] = [];
  @Input()template!:TemplateRef<any>;
}

And you use like
<list-items [items]="items" [template]="template"></list-items>
<!--see the ng-template is outside-->
<ng-template #template let-item>
    <div style="border:1px solid silver;padding:.5rem;margin:.5rem">
      <p>Id:{{item.id}}</p>
      <p>Name:{{item.name}}</p>
    </div>
</ng-template>

If we can put the template inside like a "ng-content", we can get the template using ContentChild
@Component({
  selector: 'list-items-content',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
  @if(templateRef)
  {
    @for (item of items;track $index)
    {
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="templateRef;context:{$implicit:item}">
      </ng-container>
    }
  }
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  `,
})
export class ListItemsContent {
  @Input() items: any[] = [];
  @ContentChild(TemplateRef) template!: any;
  get templateRef() {
    return this.template || null;
  }
}

And you use like
<list-items-content [items]="items">
  <ng-template let-item>
    <div style="border:1px solid silver;padding:.5rem;margin:.5rem">
      <p>Id:{{item.id}}</p>
      <p>Name:{{item.name}}</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</list-items-content>

a stackblitz with both options

But the second option is exactly what I have...  And having access to template is not the same as having access to embedded views built from that template. Still don't see where the directive could be applied. I'd rather not wrap the item in a div because that can interfere with css

@Mike, Sorry, I understand you want to have a component that you pass an array of objects and a "template" (the template can pass as @Input or using the ng-content). NOTE: If you want to apply a .css from "parent" remember that you can use some like, p.e. list-items p{color:red} -see that the list-itemsis the selector. NOTE2: if we the selector in a component is enclosed by [ ] allow use any html tag with this "attribute", e.g. selector:[list-items] you can use <div list-items>..</div>

Nah, you are missing the point. I need to know the widths of the items - for that I have an attribute directive. But the items are defined by ng-template which doesn't have width. And directive applied outside of the component can't be reached. The question is can you apply directive to templateRef

You always can add the directive in the "list-items", and use ViewChildren to get the items. As the ViewChildren is public, from parent you can get the queryList, I update the stackblitz. I don't know if can help :(
